# replace only " last word in 2nd line in a file" using file input or regex in python

Tags: python, regex, file-io

Say my file contains (read only):

```
           123.1.1.1      qwerty
          123.0.1.1      timmy
          (some text)
```

I wants to change `timmy` to some new word, but I should not use the word "timmy" anywhere in my code, because user can change it any time he wants.

Is that possible in python "go to particular line and replace last word"?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible. But where is the part showing what you tried to achieve you goal? [FAQ]

Comment: You can read a file line by line, keep a counter and only manipulate the second line. There is no need for a regular expression here.

Comment: @ppeterka  : I used re , rsplit, sed, file input but each time whole file get erase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's good to iterate over lines of a file, thus it will also work for huge files.

My approach would be

1. read input line-by-line
2. split each line
3. replace second word if on second line
4. join parts together again
5. write to output file

I split each line and join it again in order to have some consistency regarding which whitespaces are between the words. If you don't care about it, keep `line` untouched except if `idx == 1`. Then you could also `break` the loop after line 2 (`idx==1`).

```
import shutil

input_fn = "15636114/input.txt"
output_fn = input_fn + ".tmp"

replacement_text = "hey"

with open(input_fn, "r") as f_in, open(output_fn, "w+") as f_out:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f_in):
        parts = line.split()
        if idx==1:
            parts[1] = replacement_text
        line = "    ".join(parts) + "\n"
        f_out.write(line)

shutil.move(output_fn, input_fn)
```

I write to a temporary output file (in order to keep input file untouched in case of an exception), then finally I overwrite the input file with the ouput file (`shutil.move`).

Comment: :its not working "readonly" file not able to create zzz.tmp file and give permission to it.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Which file is readonly? The whole directory? If the source file is readonly, then just don't do `shutil.move` in the end and choose another, better name for the ouput file.

Comment: input_fn is a read only file and therefore output_fn also read only file.

Comment: when i run above mentioned code i get "IO Error :[error 13 ] permission denied:zzz.tmp".

Comment: mmm Maybe `open(output_fn, "w")` instead of `w+` fixes this? Does the file already exist from earlier runs?

Comment: i have tried everything w and w+, and also existing file but if i give "only read permission then it wont work, rest all condition your solution working fine.

Comment: can u please provide me any alternative solution? without creating any new file?

Comment: When I make the input file read-only, I get the IOError on the `shutil.move` line, not earlier. Which OS are you using? I really don't understand the behaviour.

Comment: I am using linux machine, not on shutil.move line , while opening file *.tmp in write mode.

Comment: This is definitely strange. I'd suspect you directory has wrong permissions. When opening the output file the underlying processes should not at all care about the permissions of the input file.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
text = """123.1.1.1      qwerty
          123.0.1.1      timmy
          (some text)
"""

import re
print re.sub(r'^(.*\n.*)\b(\w+)', r'\1hey', text)
```

Result:

```
      123.1.1.1      qwerty
      123.0.1.1      hey
      (some text)
```

Feel free to ask if you need explanations.

Comment: how can we give file name in re.sub?

Comment: :how can we write it in re.sub if "text" is a file?

Comment: you have to `open()` a file object and `read()` its contents into a variable. See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

This function will do what you want to achieve

```
def replace_word(filename, linenum, newword):
    with open(filename, 'r') as readfile:
        contents = readfile.readlines()

    contents[linenum] = re.sub(r"[^ ]\w*\n", newword + "\n", contents[linenum])

    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in python you can't simply update a file without re writing it. You'll have to do something like the following.

Say you have a file called `abcd.txt` as follows.

#### abcd.txt

```
123.1.1.1      qwerty
123.0.1.1      timmy
```

then you can do something like this.

```
 with open('abcd.txt', 'rw+') as new_file:
    old_lines = new_file.readlines() # Reads the lines from the files as a list
    new_file.seek(0) # Seeks back to index 0
    for line in old_lines:
        if old_lines.index(line) == 1: # Here we check if this is the second line
            line = line.split(' ')
            line[-1] = 'New Text' # replace the text
            line = ' '.join(line)
        new_file.write(line) # write to file
```

Comment: For each line, you search a list. What if the number of lines is huge? What if line 2 and line 248 are equal? I'd rather do `enumerate`.

Comment: even if line 2 and 248 are equal their index would differ.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something here. `line` is a string. `old_lines` is a list of strings. `old_lines.index(line)` searches for the **first** occurrence of `line` within `old_lines`, and returns the corresponding index. So if line 2 and 248 were equal, `old_lines.index(old_lines[247])` would return 1.